# How to remove nodejs from ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I have followed the below instructions to install nodejs

[Installing a tar.gz on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33033538/installing-a-tar-gz-on-linux/33033773)

---

Download the `.tar.xz` file form https://nodejs.org/en/ and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.

Then go to the destination that you downloaded your file to. For me it's my downloads folder. Then hit this command and Node.js will get installed on your system:

```
sudo tar -xf node-v16.0.0-linux-x64.tar.xz --directory=/usr/local --strip-components=1
```

---

---

Now, i want to remove node js, so i tried

```js
rahul@rahul:~$ sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove nodejs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'nodejs' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

rahul@rahul:~$ sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove node
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package node

rahul@rahul:~$ node -v
v14.17.6

rahul@rahul:~$
```

#### How can i remove?

Comment: tar has extracted files to /usr/local dir. You would have to remove manually from that location. apt would not work in this case!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I remove completly with this solution [https://stackoverflow.com/a/60701804/15725189](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60701804/15725189)